# Oracle SQL multiple left joins with duplicate records or "invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, left-join

I'm fairly new to SQL and have done some joins before but nothing as complex as this.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to join together many tables to show overall data for reporting. The main table `g`, is where I would like to see the level of detail at. `g` has a One-to-many relationship with all tables attached to it. Would a `GROUP BY` eliminate these duplicates?

I've tried using `SELECT DISTINCT`, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

Here is the output of the SQL that I'm currently running `ORA-00904: "a"."akey": invalid identifier`.

```
SELECT 
a.afield123 ORDER_QTY,
b.bfield123 MANUF,
c.cfield123 ORDER_DATE,
d.dfield123 PATIENT_CREATE_DATE,
e.efield123 PAYOR_CLASS,
f.ffield123 ID

FROM

schema123.a12345            a,
schema123.b12345            b,
schema123.c12345            c,
schema123.d12345            d,
schema123.e12345            e,
schema123.f12345            f,

LEFT JOIN schema123.g12345  g ON     
(a.akey = b.akey AND
 c.ckey = d.ckey AND 
 e.ekey = f.ekey)
```

Here's some sample data

G Table (Main Table) 
`Primary Key: gfield123`
`Foreign Keys: akey,bkey,ckey,dkey,ekey,fkey,hkey`

```
gfield123   gfield124   akey    bkey    ckey    dkey    ekey    fkey   hkey
1           8/1/2017    1234    2234    3234    4234    5234    6234   7234
```

A Table 
`Primary Key: akey`
`Foreign Keys: gfield123, bkey`

```
akey    afield123   gfield123   bkey        
1234    20          1           2234        
1235    40          1           2234
```

B Table
`Primary Key: bkey`
`Foreign Keys: gfield123, ckey, akey`

```
bkey    bfield123   gfield123 akey  ckey    
2234    COMPANY1    1         1234  3234
```

C Table
`Primary Key: ckey`
`Foreign Keys: gfield123, bkey, dkey`

```
ckey    cfield123   gfield123   bkey    dkey    
3234    8/5/2017    1           2234    4234
```

D Table
`Primary Key: dkey`
`Foreign Keys: gfield123, ckey, ekey`

```
dkey    dfield123       gfield123   ckey    ekey    
4234    7/1/2017        1           3234    5234
```

E Table
`Primary Key: ekey`
`Foreign Keys: gfield123, fkey`

```
ekey    efield123       gfield123   fkey
5234    MEDICARE        1           6234
```

F Table
`Primary Key: fkey`
`Foreign Key: gfield123`

```
fkey    ffield123         gfield123 
6234    ABC123            1
```

H Table
`Primary Key: hkey`

```
hkey    hfield123           
7234    9999
```

Expected Outcome

```
gfield123   afield123   bfield123 cfield123 efield123 ffield123 hfield123
1           60          COMPANY1  8/5/2017  MEDICARE  ABC123    9999
```

edit: SQL simplification, Data Samples, Expected Outcome

Comment: "That's a big block of code." "We're going to need a bigger debugger."

Comment: Don't mix ANSI joins with old-style Oracle syntax; in your first version rewrite all the comma-separated tables in the `from` clause into proper (inner) `join` statements with suitable `on` clauses. That mix may be why `PAY` isn't visible where you expect it to be, but is messy and confusing - to people and the optimiser - with that mix.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `SCHEMANAME.BT_PAYOR   PAY,` would look like? I'm not familiar with the difference between ANSI and old-style Oracle.

Comment: @AnthonyKnisely - `FROM
SCHEMANAME.BT_DOCTOR DOC JOIN SCHEMANAME.BT_ITEM                    ITEM ON <some condition> JOIN SCHEMANAME.BT_CMN                     CMN ON ...`, You're already using ANSI syntax for the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Man, simplify. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I down vote your question because don't helps anyone but you.

Comment: @danihp I'm brand new to SQL and posted this on this forum to learn. This can surely help somebody else in the forums looking for guidance on large joins. I believe that this is an unfair judgement. All I'm looking for is some help from someone more experienced than me and grow the community knowledge at the same time. Isn't that what this is for?

Comment: @AnthonyKnisely Trust me, you don't want to get into a debate in the comments here about the purpose of this site. Look at the MCVE link to see why this question is hard for you to get help with.

Comment: what are the Primary key and foreign keys of each of the tables defined a12345-g12345?  it seems odd to me you'd join a.akey to b.bkey.

Comment: @SandPiper, I have updated the post to reflect a more understandable view and show something that may help the community.

Comment: @xQbert a.akey would be a primary key in relation to the foreign key b.akey, where b.akey contains multiple references to a.akey.

Comment: Wow @AnthonyKnisely, nice job. I remove my down vote and turn it on a up vote. Good job man!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all records from G and only those matching in a-b-c-d-e-f then

Unless you have aggregation occurring you don't typically use a group by.  Distinct tells us that you know you have duplicates in the table joins and you want to eliminate them from the results.

```
SELECT sum(a.afield123) as ORDER_QTY
     , b.bfield123 as MANUF
     , c.cfield123 as ORDER_DATE
     , d.dfield123 as PATIENT_CREATE_DATE
     , e.efield123 as PAYOR_CLASS
     , f.ffield123 as ID
     , g.gfield123 as gkey
     , g.hfield123 as hField123
FROM schema123.g12345 g
LEFT JOIN schema123.a12345 a
  ON g.gkey = a.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.b12345 b
  ON a.akey = b.akey
 AND g.gkey = b.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.c12345 c
  ON b.bkey = c.bkey
 AND g.gkey = c.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.d12345 d
  ON c.ckey = d.ckey
 AND g.gkey = d.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.e12345 e
  ON d.dkey = e.dkey
 AND g.gkey = g.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.f12345 f
  ON e.ekey = f.ekey
 AND g.gkey = g.gkey
LEFT JOIN schema123.f12345 
  on g.hkey = h.hkey
GROUP BY , b.bfield123 as MANUF
     , c.cfield123 as ORDER_DATE
     , d.dfield123 as PATIENT_CREATE_DATE
     , e.efield123 as PAYOR_CLASS
     , f.ffield123 as ID
     , g.gfield123 as gkey
     , g.hfield123 as hField123
```

Notice we

- eliminated the comma notation in the from clause it's the 89 standard.  yes that's almost 30 years ago there was one in 92 that now uses left /right, full outer syntax.
- added g.field123 gkey to the select  why join a table if not selecting anything?
- moved the g to be the first entry in the from (you wanted all record from G and only those that matched in other table chain right?
- put a left join and an on clause for each of the joins.
- I aligned the code so that I could see if we were missing a , in select.
- assumed that key notation makes sense.
- assumed join g.gkey  = a.akey as you didn't spell out how g relates to the other tables.
- if you add a WHERE Clause, only limits on g can be added there.
- if you need to limit on values in other tables use an `AND` on the join itself such as `and d.dfield123 >= to_date('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')` so only patients created in 2017 show.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. Would `SELECT DISTINCT` in this case sum all of `ORDER_QTY` together  to reflect a total `ORDER_QTY` for that individual order? As far as the other keys, g.gkey is a primary key and would exist in all other tables as a foreign key.

Comment: No... If you need to sum then sum(a.afield123) and then add the non-aggrated fields to a group by and eliminate the distinct. For those needing to ask a question consider talking to the duck first. Yes, I'm serious.

Comment: Now maybe you want to aggregrate on other fields as well such as Max(create date) or max(order_Date) this is why I wanted to see sample data and why others asked for a MVCE.  It's not that we're being rude, it's that we want to help you in the most time efficient way for us as possible.  When you provide a MVCE with data and actual expected results on that data; the picture of what you need done becomes more clear.  In addition, the exercise in itself helps you understand the problem better. This results in less back/forth chatter that this question will likely have.

Comment: Here's the duck: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/  and updated to account for gkey being in all tables.

Comment: I've added in some sample data for reference. I will go back, try out your solution in my data, and see if it works properly, thank you.

Comment: What if have another table, H, that only has a primary key, `hkey` that only exists as a foreign key in table G? How would I pull data from table H with the current SQL? I've added in another table for reference.

Comment: Simpy add another left join add to select and group by.  Unless this field needs aggregation then add to select w/ aggregation and no group by (but still need a join)  Note left join will keep the G record and only show a H record when it exists.  Join the tables on the FK/PK relationship even if it's a compound key.